# show div when clicked and hide again after a couple of seconds

Tags: javascript, css, delay

I have this javascript:

```
function addToCart(id){

    //  alert(document.getElementById('pizza-title'+id).innerHTML);
        document.getElementById('floating-notif').setAttribute("style", "display:block; animation: fadein 2s;-moz-animation: fadein 2s; -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;-o-animation: fadein 2s;");
        setTimeout(hideFloatinDiv(), 5000);
    }

    function hideFloatinDiv(){
        document.getElementById('floating-notif').setAttribute("style", "display:none;");

    }
```

Now what I am doing is that after a button is clicked the div will show with 2 second transition animation which currently works and after 5 second it will disappear with `display none` which currently not working.

The problem is that when I put `setTimeout(hideFloatinDiv(), 5000);`
 It wont work.

Is there a way to show the div for a couple of second and hide it again in javascript or css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the function `hideFloatinDiv` immediately, instead of passing it to `setTimeout`. Take off the parentheses:

```
setTimeout(hideFLoatinDiv, 5000);
```